# Why do I have to make the variable global?

Tags: python, global

In the code below, you need to make 'total' a global variable for the code to work. Without doing so an error is raised. Why does this happen?

```
total = 0
def add_to_total(n):
    global total
    total = total + n

add_to_total(5)
print(total)
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do with this piece of code?

Comment: this is because global has been declared outside the function and if you want to access it inside the function, you have to make it a global variable. I suggest you read this documentation for better understanding. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Comment: @jimmie_roggers That's not precisely right. See my answer

Comment: You got your answer, but please be aware that using `global` is the perfect way to programmers hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If python sees something like `variable = ...` or `variable += ...` somewhere in the function, it assumes it's a local variable and will look it up in local variables. That's why you need to explicitly say that it's global.